# IllegalStateException attempt to re-open an already-closed object

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have a `TimerTask` that runs a check method every 5 seconds as so

```
TimerTask checkEnc = new mainTask();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(checkEnc 0, 5000);
```

The method checks for new data added onto the database.

```
  public static ArrayList<Media> getNew(Context context) {

    ArrayList<Media> medias = new ArrayList<Media>();

    Cursor cursor = getNewAsCursor(context);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            medias.add(new Media(context, cursor));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }


    if(cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()){
        cursor.close();
    }

    return medias;

}
```

The problem is it crashes most of the time with attempt to re-open an already-`closed object: net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteQuery` on the line

```
cursor.moveToNext();
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: What does `Media` constructor do with the cursor passed to it?